# ActiveRecord - Using a float field to 'group & order' items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on a project built on Rails 4, ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL and faced with a performance dilemma -

For brevity, let's say I have `Category` & `Item` models. `Category has_many items`.

Let's take the example where category `'Furniture'` has `'bed, large mattress, small mattress, armchair'`, etc. While displaying these items under the category, we would intuitively want to see all kinds of mattresses and bed frames together, instead of being lexicographically ordered. Also, let's assume the total number of items under any category is in the order of < 100 (mostly about ~10-15 per category) & so naturally, the order of items falling in the same 'group' under a category would be much lower than that.

To achieve this grouping, one way is to create a `SubCategory` model and associate items through them, so we can add items of a certain group later on and still be able to show them together by grouping on the category & sub category.

The other way I'm thinking of, since the order of total items is so small, is to add an `order (float type)` field to the `Item` model to still be able to group them together (Bed = 5.01, Mattress = 5.02, Chair = 6.01, Bed Cover = 5.03 & so on).

The only reason I'm considering the other option is because we're confident on the number of items to not go beyond even a 100 in our application's scope and so the Sub Category route - creating a new model and persisting many columns vs one - seems like an overkill for this particular case.

So my question (finally!) is this -

What kind of pitfalls might I fall if I went the second route? Moreover, is sorting on a float field with Postgres an overall better tradeoff on speed and memory vs adding a new model to simulate sub groupings such as mentioned in the above example?

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: First of all I would suggest design for the future and use sub category. This makes everything far more simplistic in design and extensibility. The float relies on the user or the application not only knowing the appropriate group but also the prefix to this group (leading integer) as well as the scale of < 100 and the current position of other elements. This makes for a poor design. The sub category join on the scale that you are discussing has no impactful side effects and can only be beneficial in the future when I decide bed's and mattresses now each need their own group.